# Unable to connect to mySql from index.jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have added the jdbc jar file to a libs folder and included into project. Able to connect to mysql database from a java class and perform queries and so on.

But when I try to do the same from the index.jsp page I get the error:

**No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tablename**

I have checked and there is no .Driver for me to import as com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. 
After com.mysql.jdbc. I only have util and other extensions. Based on other examples here I am supposed to use .Driver. But I am able to connect to the database in current situations via java class anyway thus not sure if this is the issue. I got the driver from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

I am using the same code in both places. Do I need additional add-ons to be able to access it from a .jsp page?

Code at java class which works:

```
    void connect(){
        try {

            //getting information from a table
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tablename", "root", "");
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM credential");
            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString("username") + " " + rs.getString("password"));
            }

            con.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Code at index.jsp which returns the above error message:

```
    <%
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tablename", "root", "");
    %>
```

Comment: Scriptlet code does not belong in JSPs.  This isn't 1998.  You should not be doing this.  Learn JSTL and server side coding.  Let Tomcat pool your data sources and use JSTL <sql> tags if you must do this.

Comment: @duffymo I am new to this. But the examples and tutorials for this were as recent as 2015. Thanks for the tip. Can I know if JSTL is present by default in the project or is there an entire bunch of steps needed where I am going to need all sorts of imports and jar dependencies for me to use it.

Comment: They are wrong. Please start learning JSTL.

Comment: New to this - then don't do the wrong thing. No script lets.

Comment: Though your approach is indeed unsuitable for new projects, you definitely do not need to learn JSTL to write modern Java webapps (nor do you need Tomcat to do your connection pooling). There are plenty of alternative frameworks, e.g. Spring MVC, with much more potential for beginners.

Comment: @AndrewRegan This is a very simple application with just 5 pages. I have already created the front end and just trying to get the database connection setup and its pretty much done. I am more used to writing in .net environment and understand that frameworks will make my life easier. Just that in this incident considering the progress of the work, I don't want to start messing about with a new framework or if possible even avoid using JSTL,

Comment: Indeed - it's not our job to tell you what frameworks to use, and in any case this doesn't answer your actual question. At a guess I would suggest your `connect()` method was getting called before your index.jsp is loaded, and because the Driver is only loaded in the latter case, the `.getConnection()` call fails because the class is not yet loaded. If this just a test app you probably don't need to worry about connection leaks, just make sure the Driver config is consistent wherever it's needed.

Comment: Do you have the MySQL JDBC driver JAR in your Tomcat /lib folder?  If not, put it there.